# gオプションを使った正規表現で、グループごとのキャプチャ文字列を取り出したい

Tags: javascript

キャプチャグループを含む正規表現を `String.prototype.match()` に渡すと、戻り値の配列から各グループのキャプチャ文字列を取り出せます。

```
console.log("a123b456".match(/(\d+)|(.+?)/));
// => ["a", undefined, "a"]
```

一方gオプションを付けると、各マッチ回のマッチ文字列全体しか入っていないようです。

```
console.log("a123b456".match(/(\d+)|(.+?)/g));
// => ["a", "123", "b", "456"]
```

Rubyでいう次のコードのように、キャプチャグループも個別に取得する方法はありますか？

```
p "a123b456".scan(/(\d+)|(.+?)/)
# => [[nil, "a"], ["123", nil], [nil, "b"], ["456", nil]]
```

Comment: [JavaScript equivalent of Ruby's String#scan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895373)

Comment: @metropolis まさにそれですね...ありがとうございます、回答に取り込ませていただきました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

キャプチャ文字列を取り出したい時は [`Regexp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) を使います。

ただし一回の呼び出しでは一回分のマッチ結果しか返さない<sup>*1</sup>ので、全件を取得したい場合は繰り返し呼び出す必要があります。
<sub>*1: 要はgオプションのない正規表現を [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) に渡した時と同じ配列が返ってくる</sub>

```js
var re=/(\d+)|(.+?)/g;
var str = "a123b456";
var result;
while ((result = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

で、これを使ってRubyの `String#scan` を再現すると、例えば次のようになります。

```js
String.prototype.scan = function(re) {
  var m, r = [];
  while ((m = re.exec(this)) !== null) {
    r.push(m.slice(1)); // sliceで[0]を取り除く
  }
  return r;
};
console.log(JSON.stringify("a123b456".scan(/(\d+)|(.+?)/g)));
```

参考 [JavaScript equivalent of Ruby's String#scan - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895373)